# REST API POST /V1/salesRules

Tags: rest, magento2

I'm getting below error while trying to create sales-rule, using Magento REST/salesRules/API.

**string(2067) "{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"rule"}**

My code:-

```
    $userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");

    $ch = curl_init("http://test.local/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);        

    $data = [
        'name' => '40% Off on Large Orders',
        'store_labels'=> [],
        'description' => 'Test sales rule',
        'website_ids' => [1,3],
        'customer_group_ids' => [0, 1, 2, 3],
        "from_date" => "2018-01-03",
        'uses_per_customer' => 0,
        'is_active' => true,
        ......
        ......
        ......
    ];

    $ch = curl_init("http://test.local/index.php/rest/V1/salesRules");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, able to successfully create a rule via salesrule API....
I was missing one line of code. Need to set the array in array 'rule'.

```
    $ruleData['rule'] = $data; //important step...

    $ch = curl_init("http://test.local/index.php/rest/V1/salesRules/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($ruleData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Getting below error after trying above approach :{"message":"Property \"Code\" does not have accessor method \"getCode\" in class \"Magento\\SalesRule\\Api\\Data\\RuleInterface\".","trace":"#0 \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/deltaint_code\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Reflection\/NameFinder.php(59): Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\NameFinder->findAccessorMethodName(Object(Zend\\Code\\Reflection\\ClassReflection), 'Code', 'getCode', 'isCode')\n#1 \/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/deltaint_code\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Webapi\/ServiceInputProcessor.php(172): M'... (length=3178)